# ¿Son posibles HTML TAGS en Javascript SIN utilizar React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

Tengo todo mi proyecto hecho con typescript y me gustaría poder incrustar etiquetas html en el código para montar una tabla ¿existe algún sistema para hacer esto sin tener que recurrir a React?
Gracias

Comment: Tu pregunta es tan rara que no la entiendo... que tiene que ver react con hacer una tabla????

Comment: De acuerdo con @gbianchi, ¿Podrías elaborar más detalles para tu pregunta?, saludos

Comment: —————————————————————————————————> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834929/how-can-i-use-html-tags-in-javascript